# How to use Tailwind CSS’s responsive design system to show a "mobile only" message when at the “md” breakpoint?

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, tailwind-css

How do I use Tailwind’s responsive design system to show a message when at the `md` breakpoint is hit, saying "Not tablet or desktop friendly - please use a mobile device."

It does not appear that Tailwind has any built in message alerts for this. I'm looking for a simple clean solution.

I have gone through the Tailwind CSS documentation, but they do not appear to cover this point.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design

Any guidance much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in Tailwind media query breakpoints to reveal a hidden banner that you have placed on the page, by using the utility classes, `hidden md:block`. For example:

```html
<div class="hidden md:block absolute inset-x-0 top-0 w-full">
  <div class="semi-bold m-2 mx-auto w-2/3 rounded border-red-700 bg-red-400 p-4 text-center text-white leading-5">
    Not tablet or desktop friendly - please use a mobile device.
  </div>
</div>
```

See this in action by resizing the window here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/v84AY6iDw4

If you want have a fancier message banner, you could use the react-toastify library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify) and display a toast when `window.innerWidth` is greater than your maximum width (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth).